# How would i retrieve the information needed from my mysql database, query specifc question

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to retrieve all locations that contain all diatoms given as input in my program (and later i want to be able to put a threshold on it so it might only need e.g. 2 of the 3 diatoms, but that is not relevant unless that would massively affect the query).
My three tables look like this (simplified,non required information left out):

| diatom |  |
| --- | --- |
| taxonKey | (unique) |
| species | (unique) |

| location |  |
| --- | --- |
| name | (unique) |
| coordinates | (unique) |

| entry |  |
| --- | --- |
| name | (from table location) |
| taxonkey | (from table diatom) |

I have as input one or more species and I want to get all locations that contain all of these species (and later a threshold value amount of these species) and all diatoms that each of these locations contain (regardless if they were in the input or not).
I used:
`select species, location.name from entry join location on location.name = entry.name join diatom on diatom.taxonKey = entry.taxonKey where species in ("Stephanodiscus neoastraea","Chaetoceros muelleri");`
("Stephanodiscus neoastraea","Chaetoceros muelleri") are some example diatoms.

With this, i get all locations that contain at least one of the input diatoms, but not only locations that contain all given. I figured I could use this result to retrieve all diatoms of each of the retrieved location in a second query. I am afraid performance might suffer with this approach. Is anyone able to help me condense these two queries into one?

to summarize:
With what query would I be able to retrieve all diatoms found in each location that contains all of the provided input diatoms in a performance friendly manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your query you mentioned two diatoms "Stephanodiscus neoastraea" and "Chaetoceros muelleri" so you need locations having both the diatoms. You can use group by with having clause to get the location names having both the diatooms.

```
select location.name 
from entry join location on location.name = entry.name 
   join diatom on diatom.taxonKey = entry.taxonKey 
   where species in ("Stephanodiscus neoastraea","Chaetoceros muelleri")
group by location.name
havig count(distinct species)=2
```

Answer (score 0):

For varying number of parameters (species)

```
-- parameters
with params(spec) as(
     select 'Stephanodiscus neoastraea' union all
     select 'Chaetoceros muelleri'
)
-- query
select location.*, diatoms.*
from (
    select entry.name 
    from entry 
    join diatom on diatom.taxonKey = entry.taxonKey 
    join params on params.spec = diatom.species
    group by entry.name
    having count(*) = (select count(*) from params)
) e
join location on location.name = e.name 
join diatom on diatom.taxonKey = e.taxonKey
```